# Is it possible to get public profiles/posts/stories etc from Instagram Graph API or any other official API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I have been trying to create an app that monitors X persons' activities across all social media platforms but so far have only been able to get my own accounts data using Instagrams Graph API and haven't been able to find a way to, for arguments sake, lets say get Taylors Swift's latest posts or something. Is it even possible?

I have tried going though the Graph API and basic display API so far but to no avail.
Expecting confirm if its even officially possible to access public profiles.